# Relative paths not work in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, systemjs, angular-router

When I'm on the `http://localhost/overview', the module is loaded along this path:

`http://localhost/app/modules/overview/overview.module.js`

But when I turn to the page `http://localhost/overview/users` and then I press F5 (refresh page), I get error:

```
Error: Unexpected token <
  Evaluating http://localhost/overview/app/modules/overview/overview.module
```

The error occurred because the URL is not correct, he should be so `http://localhost/app/modules/overview/overview.module`.

How to make it work properly?

This is project structure:

[image]

This is systemjs tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

This is systemjs config:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        baseURL: "/",
        paths: {
            'npm:': '/node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'app',

            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',

            // CDK individual packages
            '@angular/cdk/platform': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/a11y': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/bidi': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/observers': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-observers.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/overlay': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-overlay.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/portal': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-portal.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/scrolling': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-scrolling.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/keycodes': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-keycodes.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/coercion': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-coercion.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/collections': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-collections.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/rxjs': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-rxjs.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/table': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-table.umd.js',
            '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',

            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
            //Custom
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './bootstrap.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**UPDATE**

app-routing.module:

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {LoginFormComponent} from "./modules/auth/login-form/login-form.component";

const routes :Routes = [
    {path: "auth", component: LoginFormComponent},
    {path: "overview", loadChildren: "./app/modules/overview/overview.module#OverviewModule"}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{

}
```

overview.routing.module:

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {OverviewComponent} from "./overview/overview.component";

const routes :Routes = [
    {path: "", component: OverviewComponent, children:[
        {path: "users", loadChildren: "/app/modules/users/users.module#UsersModule"}
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OverviewRoutingModule{

}
```

users-routing.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {UsersListComponent} from "./users-list/users-list.component";
import {UserElementComponent} from "./user-element/user-element.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: "", component: UsersListComponent},
    {path: ":id", component: UserElementComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UsersRoutingModule { }
```

In components I use `module.id`, look for exaple overview.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: "overview",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./overview.component.html",
    providers:[
        OverviewService
    ]
})
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private overviewService :OverviewService) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        let data = this.overviewService.getOverview();
        Log.info(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: what are you using to serve static files?

Comment: @valorkin on local - nodejs server, on prod - nginx

Comment: @sanu0074 can you create a small Stackblitz code or replicate this issue . something is wrong with routes

Comment: @RahulSingh Unfortunately there is no such possibility. The project is big, and the data for pages come from the backend. So I can only try the options for solving the problems that you can offer me

Comment: how are you navigating to users ?? can you show us the code

Comment: @JayDeeEss First, the user gets to the page /overview from the AppModule. Then click on the link and go to the page /overview /users. Then press F5 and this problem is reproduced. I have described everything in the question!
What do you want me to give you? Specify more specifically! I wrote that I can not lay out the whole project, because it is closely related to the backend.

Comment: I think F5 reloads the app root path. Did you try setting a default route in your app-routing module ?

Comment: @Stanislasdrg I described everything with regard to routing in the question, look, maybe there is not enough of it?

Comment: Are You running Your app in `dev` or `prod` mode? And if in `prod` mode You need `.htaccess` file, if You using `apache` : read this official doc please: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov app run in dev mode, the server has nothing to do with it. On prod i use nodejs with nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Module routing, it doesn't pick up on the "overview" from your AppRouting lazy loading. You'd think it should, but it doesn't.

change your routes to this:

```
const routes :Routes = [
        {path: "overview", component: OverviewComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }, 
        {path: "overview/users", loadChildren: "app/modules/users/users.module#UsersModule"}
    ]}
];
```

and

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: "overview/users", component: UsersListComponent},
    {path: "overview/users/:id", component: UserElementComponent},
];
```

Edit:
https://plnkr.co/edit/pxQLNiFqltjxFtynGEgr?p=preview

Made a few changes. Put all the lazy loading into the AppRoutingModule, and added a wrapper class so Overview section can have its own router-outlet. You can see how clicking between them works with Overview and Overview 2

Comment: I think the problem is not what angular not can see route. Problem in building the wrong URL for downloading

Comment: I remove `"/:` in `{path: "overview", loadChildren: "app/modules/overview/overview.module#OverviewModule"}` and `{path: "users", loadChildren: "app/modules/users/users.module#UsersModule"}`. Now being on `http://localhost/overview/users` and press F5 - occurs redirection to `http://localhost/overwiev`, but should loaded user list.

Comment: my mistake. I missed that your overview route had a children element in it. I stripped that out and set the routes on equal nodes in my edit. If you have a children element, you will need to create add a <router-outlet> to your OverviewComponent where the children elements will be nested.

Comment: can you write example? If you need any other parts of my code, I will provide them to you

Comment: Sure I can do that, sorry a bit busy yesterday. Give me a bit of time.

Comment: sorry about the super slow reply, been busy. I added an example

Answer (score 3):

You have a leading / in the path for the user module.

Change it to be this:

```
 {path: "users", loadChildren: "app/modules/users/users.module#UsersModule"}
```

Comment: Nothing changed. It seems that the problem is not this